# jQuery: what is "input[@checked], input[@type='text']" finding?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've inherited some javascript, and it's not all working as expected at the moment. This is one sticking point:

```
jQuery("#theForm")
  .find("input[@checked], input[@type='text'], options[@selected], textarea")
  .each(function() { ... });
```

I'm not familiar with the `[@]` syntax (though it seems clear what it wants to have happen), and I'm not finding documentation. Can anyone tell me if this is valid jquery?

Comment: I'm just curious, are you serializing a form for AJAX submission here? That's what it looks like, and there are built-in methods if that's the case :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@` is an [xpath selector](http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#XPath_Selectors) (*has attribute*), which has been deprecated since jQuery 1.1.4. Just leave it out, or replace those with pseudo-selectors:

```
jQuery("#theForm")
.find("input:checked, input:text, option:selected, textarea")
.each(function() { ... });
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

The `@` in selector isn't valid now, you need to leave that out:

```
input[type='text']
```

So you should remove all instances of `@` from your code.

```
jQuery('input:checked') // gets all checked input fields
jQuery("input[type='text']")   // gets all text input fields
jQuery("select option:selected").text()  // gets text of selected option in dropdown
```

Answer (score 1):

"[...]" basically means "which has".

"@name" means attribute "name"

So "Input[@type='text']" means an text input element (`<input type='text'>`)

'@' is the correct syntax for XPath, however, it's not used by CSS, and jQuery has now switched to the CSS format, so it should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it :

- [For checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector : `input:checked`.
- For input text : `input[type=text]`
- For selected : `option:selected`

'@' will only work with some old jquery libraries because it's now deprecated.